# How to populate join table Objection.js

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, orm, objection.js

In learning how to use Objection.js, I am interested in learning how to implement a join table and populate it with the associated foreign keys. I made some progress but I'm not sure I am setting things up correctly. I created a smaller side project from my main project that is simplified so I can test without all the extra noise from the code I do not need to troubleshoot. So far, I can set this ORM up fine with no errors. Now I am interested in utilizing join tables and turn to the StackOverflow Community for any feedback I may be given. Going through the documentation, I can see that I would need to make use of the 'extra' property inside my relationMappings() method.

I made sure to create the correct mapping for each model, Actors, Movies and ActorsMovies. I also made sure to create a model for the join table. When I first started testing, I added the 'extra' property to the migration of the 'actors_movies' table as a string, then changed the data type to integer because ultimately, that is how I intend on using it. In order for this to be implemented correctly, do I only need one 'extra' property? Because I added a second 'extra' property named 'author'. So, the two are now 'character' used in the Actor model and 'author' in the Movie model.

[image]

Additional pages from Objection that I referenced are the following:
[Join Table Recipe](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/extra-properties.html) and
[Ternary relationships Recipe](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/ternary-relationships.html)

My small test comes from the examples that were provided in the Objection documentation, so that will be the point of reference I will put here. Three tables: Actors, Movies and ActorsMovies.

```
const { Model } = require('objection');
const knex = require('../db/dbConfig');

Model.knex(knex);


class Actor extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return 'actors'
    }

    static get relationMappings() {
    const Movie = require('./Movie')
      return {
        movies: {
            relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation, 
            modelClass: Movie,
            join: {
                from: 'actors.id',
                through: {
                    from: 'actors_movies.actor_id',
                    to: 'actors_movies.movie_id',
                    extra: {
                      character: 'character'
                    }
                },
                to: 'movies.id'
            }
        }
      };
    }
  }

module.exports = Actor;

//Movies.js
const { Model } = require('objection');
const knex = require('../db/dbConfig');

Model.knex(knex);


class Movie extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return 'movies'
    }

    static get relationMappings() {
    const Actor = require('./Actor')
      return {
        actors: {
            relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation, 
            modelClass: Actor,
            join: {
                from: 'movies.id',
                through: {
                    from: 'actors_movies.movie_id',
                    to: 'actors_movies.actor_id',
                    extra: {
                      author: 'author'
                    }
                },
                to: 'actors.id'
            }
        }
      };
    }
  }

module.exports = Movie;

//ActorsMovies.js
const { Model } = require('objection');
const knex = require('../db/dbConfig');

Model.knex(knex);


class ActorsMovies extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
      return 'actors_movies';
    }
  
    static get idColumn() {
      return ['actor_id', 'movie_id'];
    }
  
    static get relationMappings() {
    const Actor = require('./Actor');
    const Movie = require('./Movie');
      return {
        actor: {
          relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
          modelClass: Actor,
          join: {
            from: 'actors_movies.actor_id',
            to: 'actors.id'
          }
        },
  
        movie: {
          relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
          modelClass: Movie,
          join: {
            from: 'actors_movies.movie_id',
            to: 'movies.id'
          }
        }
      };
    }
  }
  

module.exports = ActorsMovies;
```

For this test project, I am interested in making sure the ActorsMovies table gets correctly populated with the actor_id and the movie_id when a movie is created with a POST request.

```
// api/actors.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Actors = require('../models/Actor');
const Movies = require('../models/Movie');

/************************/
/********* READ *********/
/************************/

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const user = await Actors.query();
        res.status(200).json(user)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
});

router.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const actorId = req.params.id;
        const actor = await Actors.query().findById(actorId);

        const movie = await Actors.relatedQuery('movies')
            .for(actor.id)
            .insert({ name: actor.name, character: actor.id }).debug()
            
        res.status(200).json(movie)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
});

module.exports = router;

// api/movies.js 
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Movies = require('../models/Movie');

/************************/
/********* READ *********/
/************************/

router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const movie = await Movies.query();
        res.status(200).json(movie)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
});

router.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const movieId = req.params.id;
        const movie = await Movies.query().findById(movieId);

        const actor = await Movies.relatedQuery('actors')
            .for(movie.id)
            .insert({ name: 'The Room', author: movie.id }).debug();

        res.status(200).json(actor)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
});

/************************/
/******** CREATE ********/
/************************/

router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const createMovie = req.body;
        const newMovie = await Movies.query().insert(createMovie);

        const actor = await Movies.relatedQuery('actors')
            .for(newMovie.id)
            .insert({ name: newMovie.name, author: newMovie.id }) 

        res.status(201).json(actor)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

```
//migration file 

exports.up = knex => {
    return knex.schema
      .createTable('actors', table => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.string('name');
        table.timestamps(false, true);
      })
      .createTable('movies', table => {
        table.increments('id').primary();
        table.string('name');
        table.timestamps(false, true);
      })
      .createTable('actors_movies', table => {
        table.integer('actor_id').references('actors.id');
        table.integer('movie_id').references('movies.id');
        // The actor's character's name in the movie.
        table.integer('character');
        table.integer('author');
        table.timestamps(false, true);
      });
  };

  exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema
      .dropTableIfExists('actors_movies')
      .dropTableIfExists('movies')
      .dropTableIfExists('actors')
  };

// dbConfig.js
require('dotenv').config();
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const config = require('../knexfile.js')[environment]

module.exports = require('knex')(config)
```

The server works fine, the connection between knex.js and Objection.js is fine too. I get a clean response in Postman, but I'm hoping to get an experienced opinion on how I am implementing this. As a side note, I did scour StackOverflow and did not find my specific question, so your feedback will be greatly appreciated.